# Countdown timer with automatic reset

Tags: javascript

I'm building this countdown timer where it starts 3 days from now, but when it reaches half day (6 hours), it resets itself back to three days from that point.

I made this code but I don't know how to make it automatic. The few options I tried were resetting it to 3 days on every load. Right now I have a hardcoded date.

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Jul 8, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + ":" + hours + ":"
  + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  if (distance < 0) {
  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Since the posted code work as is, it is unclear what you ask. What does _"make it automatic"_ really mean?

Comment: When it reaches 0 it goes to `-1...`. I don't want to hard code the date and deploy it every three days but I'd like it to be automated, it should reset itself to three days when it reaches 6 hours